# magento memory problem, cannot unset objects 

Tags: php, memory, magento, export, unset

i am writing a magento product exporter, that writes a couple of attributes into a csv file. one attribute is called the "category string" and its method looks like:

```
...
foreach($products as $_product) {       
        ...

        $productId      = $_product->getSku();
        $productCategory    = getCategoryString($_product['category_ids']);
        ...
}
...

function getCategoryString($numbers) {

    $catString = '';
    $catModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $ex = explode(',', $numbers);

    foreach ($ex as $i =>  $e) {

        if ($i > 0) {

            $catString .= $catModel->load($e)->getName();

            if ($i < (count($ex)-1))
                $catString .= ' > ';
        }
    }

    $ex = NULL;
    $numbers = NULL;

    $catModel->unsetData();
            unset($catModel);
            $catModel = NULL;

    return $catString;
}
```

but after each iteration the method call costs about 1MB for each product and i have about 9000 products! i cannot clean up the $catModel variable! the $catModel = NULL and unset($catModel) lines have no effects. what am i doing wrong? how can i force to unset the object?!

Comment: don't load the category in get the same data from collection you are doing pointless loading of objects here

Comment: Magento has a memory leak for loading some models (like product and category). You're probably best off trying to get this as an array of integers and working from there.

Comment: Echoing that Joseph said, PHP's conservative when releasing certain circular object references and other deeply nested object chains, which means even though your main object is being deallocated, its many sub-objects are not. Anyone's who's untangled this hasn't seen fit to share it with the world, so you're SOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with a cron for Magento, I know that it isn't the best way to do it but we needed to do it quickly.

Our solution was creating a new PHP file with the necessary code to do one single operation. From magento we get a product list and then call with exec() to this external PHP file product by product.

Something like this:

```
foreach($products as $_product) {       
        ...

        exec("do_the_work.php {$_product->getSku()}");

        ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it won't help unless you like to fix your teeth through ass :) sorry for being rude here but this is absolutely a big nono

Comment: I completely agree with you, that's because I said "it isn't the best way to do it".

Comment: thanks for your workaround, you are right "it isn't the best way to do it" - but it is the fastest one! everything works fine after calling an external php file for processing a product. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so your script would be so much cooler if you

1. get all catalog ids from all the products you have as an array
2. load the category collection with IN() clause with the category names you need
3. foreach your product collection one more time and select the neccecary category id's from preloaded collection with just the right elements
4. profit $$$$ cause you are not using memory like its unlimited for you

much much cooler thing would be joining the category names directly to product collection, that would consume even less resources